# Store output from for loop in an array

Tags: python, arrays, append

I am still at the very beginning of my Python journey, so this question might be basic for more advanced programmers.

I would like to analyse a bunch of .wav files, that are all stored in the same directory, so I created a list of all the filenames so I could then get their audiosignal and samplerate.

```
dirPath=r"path_to_directory"
global files
files = [f for f in os.listdir(dirPath) if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(dirPath, f)) and f.endswith(".wav")]
for file_name in files:
    path_to_file= dirPath+"\\"+file_name
    audio_signal, sample_rate = sf.read(path_to_file)
```

with `sf` being the `soundfile` library.

`audio_signal` is an array, `sample_rate` is a number.

Now I would like to be able to store both `audio_signal` and `sample_rate` together with the  corresponding `file_name`, so I can access them later. How do I do this?

I tried

```
files = [f for f in os.listdir(dirPath) if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(dirPath, f)) and f.endswith(".wav")],[]
for file_name in files[0]:
    path_to_file= dirPath+"\\"+file_name
    audio_signal, sample_rate = sf.read(path_to_file)
    files[1].append(audio_signal)
    files[2].append(sample_rate)
```

which seems to work, but is there a more elegant way? I feel like the `audio_signal`, `sample_rate` and `file_name` are individual values rather than codependent.

Comment: I'm not sure that the code you have shown really works, as far as I can tell `files[2]` doesn't exist and should give an error.

Comment: @mkrieger1 yup, you're right. it existed in the original code but got lost somehow when i copied it here.

Comment: please don't construct filenames by adding two strings via `\\ ` . instead use `os.path.join()` (aka: get yourself into a habit of writing cross-platform code)

Comment: @umläute thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data structure you are looking for is an *associative array* which associates a *key* with a *value* – the key being the file name and the value being a tuple consisting of the audio signal and sample rate in this example.

An implementation of associative arrays is built into Python as the *dictionary* type.

You can learn about dictionaries here:
https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries

The application in your code would look like:

```
result = {}

for file_name in files:
    # as before:
    # ...
    audio_signal, sample_rate = ...
    # new:
    result[file_name] = audio_signal, sample_rate
```